# tkinter unwanted function overwriting

Tags: python, function, animation, canvas, tkinter

so basically i have a function with an animation of 1 object and i want to be able to have more independent objects, however when i call the function again it only overwrites the old one and i want to be able to have multiple objects (i want rain)

```py
import  random
import tkinter
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(width=1000, height=600, bg="white")
canvas.pack()

x = 0
y = 0

def idk():
    idk2()
    canvas.after(2000,idk2)

def idk2():
    global x
    x = random.randint(0,1000)
    idk3()

def idk3():
    global y
    y = y+10
    canvas.delete('idk3')
    canvas.create_rectangle(x-2,y-10,x+2,y+10,tag="idk3")
    if y<600:
        canvas.after(50, idk3)

idk()
```

Comment: ***"to have multiple objects"***: Why do you delete to old one then? Refere this example: [how-do-i-change-these-two-balls-into-many-of-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632979/how-do-i-change-these-two-balls-into-many-of-them/53691750)

Comment: sorry, im looking for a simple solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want many falling rain, you need to save the rain drops before they reach the ground.

Below is an example:

```
raindrops = {}

def raining():
    # update existing rain drops
    for rd in list(raindrops):
        if raindrops[rd] < 600:
            # keep rain falling
            raindrops[rd] += 10
            canvas.move(rd, 0, 10)
        else:
            # rain drop reaches the ground, remove it
            canvas.delete(rd)
            del raindrops[rd]
    # create new rain drop at random x
    x = random.randint(0, 1000)
    rd = canvas.create_line(x, 0, x, 20)
    raindrops[rd] = 0  # save the y of rain drop
    canvas.after(20, raining)
```

Comment: i will change some things here and there, but thanks for the main functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this line from your code:

```
canvas.delete('idk3')
```

And of course call the idk() function once more

Comment: nonono i mean i want to make a "rain" so this doesn't help me at all, without this deletion it's just a bigger mess

Comment: I don't understand. You want to make 2 falling element at the same time?

Comment: yes, exactly, i would like to have many falling elements, i just dont want to have many many rows of code so i wonder how to draw more of them independently with one shared function

Comment: It's not that easy as you expect. Here is a tutorial about a falling snow in python: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Quof1cOsaOw

Comment: thanks, but it's trough pygame and not tkinter, i will be adding some conditions to my animation later when i can get more elements, but as i saw his method was completely different from mine, so i'm not going to try to rewrite his pygame method in tkinter (cause i want to stay with tkinter), that would only cause more complications